# Angular mat-select, having trouble setting values

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to build a component that has several (dynamically created) select dropdowns, to use as search filters.  The selected filters should show in chips, which I have working, the problem I have is when removing a filter I want to update the selected options in the dropdowns.

I have read several related answers here but can't get it working. Am I missing something obvious?

Here is a Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular9-material-baseline-yxr1sw

Choose an option from each select, then remove one chip - both selects are cleared.

What do I need to change to get them to update correctly?

Comment: I think the problem here is this `isSelected` field in FilterOption.ts class. The select doesnt recognize this field, so when you try to subscribe `this.productFiltersService.selectedFiltersChanged.subscribe()` here, update value it resets them.

Comment: In my view problem lies with subscribe event in filter-select component. As it is subscribing multiple times due to For Loop it is invoking multiple times for whenever remove event is triggered..

Comment: Let me ask you something...when you remove one chip you want to update all selects or just remove the selected items from that select?Cause now you are updating them all and because isSelected is not recognized it set all selects to "null"(With no checked value.like initialization)

Comment: @tufonas I only want to update the relevant select in this case, where I'm removing one of the filters, but probably the behaviour of "update them all" will be needed anyway because A) I'm updating productFilters in the service, which is the list of everything and will be used to build the request to the database and B) in future I want the filters to be in the URL so I'll parse that and need to set the selected options then (ie when loading the page new when navigating here directly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `item.value` as the `value` for your `mat-option`.

```html
filter-select.component.html

<mat-option *ngFor="let item of productFilter.options" [value]="item.value">{{item.name}}</mat-option>
```

Those values are primitive so you don't need a `compareWith` function.

```html
<mat-select multiple [formControl]="filterSelect" (openedChange)="openedChange($event)">

// [compareWith]="compareFn" removed
```

And only set your formControl to those item values

```ts
filter-select.component.ts

ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.productFiltersService.selectedFiltersChanged.subscribe(
    (newFilters: ProductFilter[]) => {
      const values = newFilters
        .find(f => f.name === this.productFilter.name)
        .options
        .filter(o => o.isSelected) // <-- only take selected options
        .map(o => o.value); // <-- only take values
      console.log("filterSelect setValue", values);
      this.filterSelect.setValue(values);
    }
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular9-material-baseline-vguwxd?file=src/app/filter-select.component.html